# VB.NET: DGV issue or SQL Server issue

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, datagridview, visual-studio-2013

G'day everyone.

What I have:

`tblTickets` table:

```
PK: TicketsID
FK: SourcesID
```

`tblSources` table:

```
PK: SourcesID
SourcesName
```

I'm using the DataGridView in VB in Visual Studio 2013 and trying to figure out how I can get the columns (I do know about hiding the un-needed columns later) synced up with TicketsID (1?) = SourcesName (1).

Mind you there's 15 more tables all relying on that TicketsID but for simplicity's sake I copied a field over for clarification.

Right now I have it where it only shows the first TicketsID in the TicketsID column and then the first SourcesName in the SourcesName column rather then having it be somehow based on TicketsID field in the tblTickets.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
Here's a screenshot of our DB that was sent to QA. It's got a lot more then just tickets in it but the setup is the same.

[image: DB image]

Answer (score 0):

So I guess what you are trying to do is display tblTickets in your datagridview and for the particular TicketsID, you want to show the SourceName for that TicketsID. Your query should join both tables tblTickets and tblSourse, The Query should look like this:

```
Select   T.TicketsID, S.SourceName
From     tblTickets T
Join     tblSource S
On       T.SourceID = S.SourseID
Order By T.ticketsID;
```

I think this is what you meant to ask, I hope it helps...

Comment: How should the PK's/FK's be setup? It's saying that the schema is different?

Comment: The way I would go about this is first figure out one-to-many relationships, in other words prepare DBDL for your tables, I am not sure what each tables are for so I can't tell you much, but please post more information on your tables and we can go from there...The key in one to many relationship is that the table with one has the foreign key of the table with many...

Comment: Updated with an image I had in Outlook.

Comment: Ok, the tables look fine, now if you want to know how to make the query from this, the easiest way is to run the query in access it self using create query, then just go to SQL view instead of design view to get the query statement, copy paste in your vb.net program, and it should work just fine